# Problem with paramter popup with multi-value field in MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, multivalue

I have the following SQL query:

```
FROM Registration AS r
WHERE r.RegisteredFor.Value=[Forms]![RunQueries]![filterBy];
```

When I run this query it reports back fine, however, when I run a second query which uses this query, so for example:

```
SELECT reg.Gender, Count(reg.Gender) AS CountOfGender, 
    Round(Count(reg.Gender)*100/(SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM FirstQuery),1) AS Percentage
FROM FirstQuery AS reg
GROUP BY reg.Gender;
```

It always either pops up a parameter box asking for "r.RegisteredFor.Value", or alternatively if I try tweaking things, it starts complaining about aggregate functions in the "Percentage" part.

If I remove the r.RegisteredFor.Value from the WHERE, or replace it with something else everything works fine. I've tried replacing the "=" in the first query WHERE with "in", and even used a SELECT to check these values on the RegisteredFor linked table, but nothing stops the parameter box from popping up.

Comment: Is there a reason you did not include your full first query (i.e. the `SELECT` part)?

Comment: Yes - the actual initial query is more complex than the one I showed - it's just so I don't have to copy and paste the same query multiple times, and so that it can be modified without changing it on 6 other child queries. However, yes - good question, I've realised that maybe the easiest way to achieve what I want is just to replicate the queries each time rather than do them separately, and just copy and paste if the initial query ever needs to change.

Comment: I meant now for the sake of this question. It might be pertinent to your post.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You might consider conditional aggregation instead.  Assuming you have two genders, `"M"` and `"F"`:

```
SELECT SUM(IIF(reg.Gender = "M", 1, 0)) AS m_cnt,
       SUM(IIF(reg.Gender = "F", 1, 0)) AS f_cnt,
       AVG(IIF(reg.Gender = "M", 100.0, 0)) AS m_percent,
       AVG(IIF(reg.Gender = "F", 100.0, 0)) AS f_percent
FROM FirstQuery AS reg;
```

Comment: Thanks for this idea, unfortunately we also need to do this on fields where there maybe multiple possibilities that may be updated over time (e.g. Ethnicity).

Comment: @terrarium . . . My recommendation is to switch databases.  This would be easier in any other database.  That said, you probably need to use a temporary table.

Comment: yes, I definitely would ditch Access in a second if it was my choice!